awk confuse columns when printing tabulated files
I have a simple problem with awk but I don't know how to solve it.
The command is this
awk '{print $1"\t"$7"\t"$8"\t"$4}' RACP_primers_v4.0.bed

and the input file looks like this
head  RACP_primers_v4.0.bed
chr2    197401726       197401984       SF3B1_742-781_F_P5      0       +       197401750       197401960
chr2    197401726       197401984       SF3B1_742-781_R_P5      0       -       197401750       197401960
chr2    197401930       197402137       SF3B1_700-740_F_P5      0       +       197401955       197402117
chr2    197401930       197402137       SF3B1_700-740_R_P5      0       -       197401955       197402117
chr2    197402603       197402673       SF3B1_662-666_F_P5      0       +       197402625       197402655
chr2    197402603       197402673       SF3B1_662-666_R_P5      0       -       197402625       197402655
chr2    197402737       197402873       SF3B1_622-626_F_P5      0       +       197402757       197402847
chr2    197402737       197402873       SF3B1_622-626_R_P5      0       -       197402757       197402847
chr2    208248338       208248464       IDH1_R132_F_P5  0       +       208248363       208248440
chr2    208248338       208248464       IDH1_R132_R_P5  0       -       208248363       208248440

or like this

So I think the format of the file is OK.
The problem is that the awk command returns this
chr2    SF3B1_742-781_F_P57401960
chr2    SF3B1_742-781_R_P57401960
chr2    SF3B1_700-740_F_P57402117
chr2    SF3B1_700-740_R_P57402117
chr2    SF3B1_662-666_F_P57402655
chr2    SF3B1_662-666_R_P57402655
chr2    SF3B1_622-626_F_P57402847
chr2    SF3B1_622-626_R_P57402847
chr2    IDH1_R132_F_P5  208248440
chr2    IDH1_R132_R_P5  208248440
chr5    NPM1_860_F_P5   171410598
chr5    NPM1_860_R_P5   171410598
chr7    EZH2_19_F_P5    148807761
chr7    EZH2_19_R_P5    148807761
chr7    EZH2_18_F_P5    148809163
chr7    EZH2_18_R_P5    148809163


and in some lines also this
chr17   TP53_11_F_P5717
chr17   TP53_11_R_P5717
chr17   TP53_10_F_P5734
chr17   TP53_10_R_P5734
chr17   TP53_09_F_P5638
chr17   TP53_09_R_P5638
chr17   TP53_08_F_P5868
chr17   TP53_08_R_P5868
chr17   TP53_07_F_P5328


Why??

It's hard to see what you are asking. Does the file have DOS line endings? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings

Apologies. The issue is that awk is not doing the command. Instead of printing column 1, 7, 8 and 4 is doing weird things as shown at the end of the post

Thank you so much. in I found the answer in your link
dos2unix filename

For more readability, use OFS variable: awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} {print $1, $7, $8, $4}'

You can strip the CRLF before printing: awk -v OFS='\t' '{sub(/\r$/,""); print$1,$7,$8,$4}'

You should also be setting FS or you'll get a surprise if you ever have an empty field since by default awk will treat multiple contiguous tabs or other white space as a single field separator.
